# python error - print(i.price) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'price' - Sorry such a long question but hoping all info is provided

Tags: python

I am trying to create an object oriented program in python for an online toy store.

I have several different classes such as shopping_cart and products.

I have tried to create a function which calculates the total price of the shopping cart but keep getting the following error:

**AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'price'**

```
#Creating shopping cart class
from products import *

class ShoppingCart:
def __init__(self, itemQuantity, productID, itemPrice, totalPrice, supplier):
    self.itemQuantity = itemQuantity
    self.productID = productID
    self.itemPrice = itemPrice
    self.totalPrice = totalPrice
    self.supplier = supplier

def displayCart(self):
    print()
    if shopping_cart == []:
        print(''' Your Shopping Cart is Empty''')
    else:
        for i in shopping_cart:
            print(i)

def add_products(self):
    item = input('''Please enter the item you wish to add to your shopping cart''')
    for obj in products:
        if item in obj.name:
            shopping_cart.append(item)
            print(item + " has been added to your cart")
            break
        else:
            print("Error this product has not been found ")

def totalprice(self):
    total = 0
    for i in shopping_cart:
        print(i.price)
        cost = i.price
        print('Your total is' + str(cost))
    shopping_cart = []
```

**there is an issue with the def totalprice function, to do with it not having a string object, is this linked to the product class, which is within a different file and shown below**

```
#creating store products
from shopping_cart import *

class Products:
def __init__(self, name, id, price, quantity, supplier):
    self.name = name
    self.id = id
    self.price = price
    self.quantity = quantity
    self.supplier = supplier

  def listProducts(self):
      print("Store Products:")

  for obj in products:
      print(obj.name + ' £' + obj.price)


  def addProduct(self, name, id, price, quantity, supplier):
      self.name = name
      self.id = id
      self.price = price
      self.quantity = quantity
      self.supplier = supplier

      addproduct = input("Please select the product you wish to add to your Shopping Cart:")
      products.append(Products('name', id, 'price', quantity, "supplier"))

      def removeProduct(self):
          item = input("Please select which product to remove:")
          products.remove(item)
          print(item + " has been removed")

    products=[]   
    products.append(Products('Playdough', 2212,'15.00', 100, "B"))
    products.append(Products('Robot', 2213,'20.00', 100, "B"))
    products.append(Products('Book', 2214,'05.00', 100, "B"))
```

Comment: You have `shopping_cart.append(item)`, where `item` is the user-inputted string, meaning you're filling `shopping_card` with strings. Perhaps you meant `shopping_cart.append(obj)`?

Answer (score 2):

Into shopping cart you append item, which has no name attribute. Instead you should append obj as you'd want the name attribute of the object. Changing `item` to `obj` will fix it and get rid of the error.

As a word of warning, consider passing setting `shopping_cart` as an instance variable of `ShoppingCart` as well as passsing the list `Products` as an argument. I think that'll make your code better as to make the scope of passing and knowing where the variables are much easier. Right now, you have all of them as read only and they don't belong to a specific object of `ShoppingCart`.